Do anonymity and neutrality imply a weak form of positionality?
I am wondering whether the axioms of anonymity and neutrality imply a weak form of positionality.
In order to state my question, let $N$ be a finite set of voters, let $A$ be a finite set of alternatives, let $\Delta$ be the set of all lotteries over $A$, let $\mathcal{P}=(\mathcal{P}_i)_{i\in N}$ be the set of all linear order profiles on $A$, and let $\sigma:\mathcal{P}\to\Delta$ be a social choice function.
ANONYMITY
Let $\Pi=\{\pi\in N^N\mid\pi\text{ is bijective}\}$ be the set of all permutations of the voter set. Then, given any profile $P\in\mathcal{P}$ and any permutation $\pi\in\Pi$, let the profile $\pi P=(P_{\pi(i)})_{i\in N}\in\mathcal{P}$ satisfy, for all voters $i\in N$ and all alternatives $x,y\in A$, $x\pi P_iy$ if and only if $xP_{\pi(i)}y$.

Anonymity. A social choice function $\sigma:\mathcal{P}\to \Delta$ is anonymous if and only if it is independent of voters' identities. Formally, if and only if
\begin{gather}\label{eq.a}
    (\forall P\in\mathcal{P})(\forall\pi\in\Pi)[\sigma(P)=\sigma(\pi P)]
\end{gather}

NEUTRALITY
Let $=\{\mu\in A^A\mid\mu\text{ is bijective}\}$ be the set of all permutations of the alternative set. Then, given any profile $P\in\mathcal{P}$ and any permutation $\mu\in M$, let the profile $\mu P\in\mathcal{P}$ satisfy, for all voters $i\in N$ and all alternatives $x,y\in A$, $\mu(x)\mu P_i\mu(y)$ if and only if $x P_iy$.

Neutrality. A social choice function $\sigma:\mathcal{P}\to \Delta$ is neutral if and only if it is independent of alternatives' labels. Formally, if and only if
\begin{gather}\label{eq.n}
    (\forall P\in\mathcal{P})(\forall\mu\in M)(\forall x\in A)[(\sigma(P))(x)=(\sigma(\mu P))(\mu(x))]
\end{gather}

QUESTION

If a voting rule is neutral and anonymous, is it true that the weights it assigns to any alternative depend exclusively on the number of times each alternative appears in every position in voters' rankings?

If the above statement is not true, what additional axiom(s) do I need for such a consequence to be true?


EXAMPLE
Consider this particular example with $N=\{1,2,3\}$, $A=\{x,y,z,w\}$ and these preference profiles $P,P'\in\mathcal{P}$:
\begin{array}{ccc}
 P_1 & P_2 & P_3 \\\hline 
 w & x & y \\ 
 z & y & x \\
 x & w & z \\
 y & z & w 
\end{array}
\begin{array}{ccc}
 P_1’ & P_2' & P_3' \\\hline 
 z & y & x \\ 
 w & x & y \\
 x & z & w \\
 y & w & z 
\end{array}
Given any alternative $a\in A$ and any profile $\tilde{P}\in\{P,P'\}$, let $a(\tilde{P})=(p_1,p_2,p_3)$ be the vector in which $p_i$ denotes the position in which alternative $a$ appears in voter $i$'s ranking. Then, we have
\begin{gather}
    x(P)=(3,1,2)\quad x(P')=(3,2,1)\\
    y(P)=(4,2,1)\quad y(P')=(4,1,2)\\
    z(P)=(2,4,3)\quad z(P')=(1,3,4)\\
    w(P)=(1,3,4)\quad w(P')=(2,4,3)
\end{gather}
Observe that $z(P)=w(P')$ and that $w(P)=z(P')$. Further, observe also that the vectors $x(P)$ and $x(P')$ contain the same numbers (i.e., $1$, $2$ and $3$) but in a different order; and that the vectors $y(P)$ and $y(P')$ also contain the same numbers (i.e., $1$, $2$ and $4$) but in a different order.
In the context of this example, what I am wondering is the following:

Do anonymity and neutrality suffice for a voting rule to satisfy the following equalities?
\begin{gather}
(\sigma(P))(x)=(\sigma(P'))(x)\\
(\sigma(P))(y)=(\sigma(P'))(y)\\
(\sigma(P))(z)=(\sigma(P'))(w)\\
(\sigma(P))(w)=(\sigma(P'))(z)
\end{gather}
If anonymity and neutrality are not sufficient to ensure these equalities hold, which additional axiom(s) make them hold true?

EDIT I have found Young’s (1975) paper, where he gives a formulation of symmetric (i.e., anonymous and neutral) deterministic social choice functions. I am unsure whether eq (1) in said paper gives a positive answer to my question, but maybe someone here can tell whether this is true or not.
